# How to get oil out of untreated maple plywood?

Tags: wood, cleaning

I got a nice sheet of maple plywood from the home center to finish a bench project for my home. I hadn't stained/sealed it yet. My kids somehow snuck into the basement with dirty hands, and wiped it all over the wood. I don't know what kind of cleaning product I should use to get oil/food stains out of the wood. I'm afraid a wet product might cause the material to warp.

Answer (score 2):

If it truly is *all over it* your best solution will likely be to sand it down.

I would get some 220 sandpaper and get after it.

I wouldn't try any cleaners as they may absorb into the grain and prevent you from properly finishing it later on.

Comment: How does sanding remove a _penetrating_ contaminant from a thin veneer?

Comment: @isherwood It is likely only on the surface, I didn't think to try alcohol or mineral spirits, that's a good idea as well. Upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

I think I'd try to dissolve the oil with something like alcohol or mineral spirits to remove at least some of it. Dab the solvent on and immediately dab with a clean, dry cloth to extract what you can.

After that, sand to restore smoothness only. The veneer is likely very thin, so you can't go nuts here. Then assess. If the stains persist you'll have to decide whether your finishing plans will hide them. Otherwise replace the boards at your kids' expense. Time for a lesson in accountability.